# locking for web applications with multiple servers

Tags: transactions, locking, flask-sqlalchemy, race-condition, flask-socketio

Friends and I have been making a game site lately. Users of our site create and join games consisting of 2-9 players each. Currently, we have one server instance handling all our site’s traffic (mostly websocket connections) and one corresponding database. We’ve experienced race conditions in the past when two requests from a same game concurrently try to alter the database, so we’ve implemented file locks in our server backend for each game.id (using the iLock library). Does this behavior lend itself well to scaling and what are the best practices for locking in when using multiple servers (i.e. auto-scaling) such as Google App Engine?

Thank you so much!